SUM of 2-way Weighted Grid in Excel

Hi friends, In the above example grid, I am looking for a formula or function that can find the sum of all Data elements with their weighted products. Below is an example pattern in terms of calculation -
Data Range: D5 : N7
Formula I am looking for is : Data (Range) * Weight A (In the same col) * Weight B (In the same row)
D5 * D4 * C5 + E5 * E4 * C5 ... + N5 * N4 * C5 +
D6 * D4 * C6 + .................+ N6 * N4 * C6 +
................................. N7 * N4 * C7

One way I know I could solve this is by calculating SUM at column and row levels and then adding them up to get a 'Grand Total'. However, I have a feeling there is a better and efficient way of solving this.
If anyone has any insights/suggestions, please help!

The row/column solution is certainly the most expeditious, especially if you don't need the individual values.

Did you try SUMPRODUCT()? What would be your desired output?

@Harun24hr Yes, I did, I was not able to get it to work, maybe I was too into the problem. The solution in fact was simple as Tom suggested

I think it's just
=SUM(D5:N7*D4:N4*C5:C7)


I checked the total using
=D$4*D5*$C5

and copying down and across.

I did it the hard way:
=LET(_Data,A1:D3,_Rows,ROWS(_Data),_Cols,COLUMNS(_Data),
_HeadRow,TAKE(_Data,1,_Cols*(-1)+1),
_HeadCol,TAKE(_Data,_Rows*(-1)+1,1),
_Body,DROP(_Data,1,1),
_Calc,MAKEARRAY(_Rows-1,_Cols-1,LAMBDA(a,b,INDEX(_Body,a,b)*INDEX(_HeadRow,1,b)*(INDEX(_HeadCol,a,1)))),
_Sum,SUM(_Calc),
_Sum)


Cross referenced with Tom's answer, I'm getting the same.
Advantage of my overcomplicated approach: if your data set changes, you only have one selection of data to make.

I feel you Excellor. I was going down that path and then stopped telling myself, it's Excel, it's purpose is to deal with similar structured data. MS cannot make it this hard to find what I was looking for. That's when I decided to get communities input. The above answer from Tom is what it should have been. I will upvote your solution too, because I think someone might find this approach useful.

Well got to challenge myself, so thanks for that. And like I just edited in: mine only uses one range, so if your data set changes you only have to adjust the one. (although 3 ranges isn't even that much/hard). Glad you found what you're looking for.

I was on the point of posting something using makearray as well before I realised I didn't have to.

DROPping in to take Tom's for fun (using broadcasting):
=LET(
    tb, C4:N7,
    w_a, DROP(TAKE(tb, 1), , 1),
    w_b, DROP(TAKE(tb, , 1), 1),
    data, DROP(tb, 1, 1),
    SUM(w_a * w_b * data)
)


=MMULT(D5:N7*D4:N4*C5:C7,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(D4:N4))^0)
Or =BYROW(D5:N7*D4:N4*C5:C7,LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))
Or I believe ETA was rolled out to production (can't test this on my mobile):
=BYROW(D5:N7*D4:N4*C5:C7,SUM)
Edit:
Oops, I thought you wanted a row wise total. Than a SUM(product) would do, which is already posted.
